# different date range for ios versions

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator

when calling method for simulator 
**version 6.1 it shows:**
 year---2012
 week no---52
 weekday---2
 **resultdate---2012-12-16 18:30:00 +0000**
 date time is 17 Dec 2012 To 23 Dec 2012
 **version 5.0 it shows:**
 year---2012
 week no---52
 weekday---2
 **resultdate---2012-12-23 18:30:00 +0000**
 date time is 24 dec. 2012 To 30 dec. 2012

```
 NSCalendar *gregorian                               = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
gregorian.Locale                                    = [NSLocale currentLocale];
//[gregorian setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
gregorian.firstWeekday                              = 2; // Sunday = 1, Saturday = 7


NSDateComponents *components                        = [gregorian components:NSYearForWeekOfYearCalendarUnit |NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit |NSWeekdayOrdinalCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

[components setYearForWeekOfYear:2012];
[components setWeekOfYear:52];
[components setWeekdayOrdinal:2];
NSLog(@"year---%ld",(long)[components yearForWeekOfYear]);
NSLog(@"week no---%ld",(long)[components weekOfYear]);
NSLog(@"weekday---%ld",(long)[components weekdayOrdinal]);

NSDate                  *resultDate                 = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];
NSLog(@"resultdate---%@",resultDate);
NSDate                  *startOfTheWeek;
NSDate                  *endOfWeek;
NSTimeInterval          interval;
[gregorian rangeOfUnit:NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit startDate:&startOfTheWeek interval:&interval forDate:resultDate];
endOfWeek                                           = [startOfTheWeek dateByAddingTimeInterval:interval-1];
```

and to get the out put dateformatter used is

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter          = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy"];
    NSString *str_StartOfTheWeek            = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:startOfTheWeek];
    NSString *str_EndOfWeek                 = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:endOfWeek];
    NSLog(@"date time is %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ To %@",str_StartOfTheWeek,str_EndOfWeek]);
    return                                 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ To %@",str_StartOfTheWeek,str_EndOfWeek];
```

how to solve this issue pls help.

Comment: I have checked it. And I am unable to reproduce it again.

Comment: @KrishnaKumar have u checked it on different simulators...

Answer (score 0):

To set a weekday (e.g. 2 = Monday) you have to use the `NSWeekdayCalendarUnit` and `setWeekday:`, not `NSWeekdayOrdinalCalendarUnit` and `setWeekdayOrdinal:`:

```
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:NSYearForWeekOfYearCalendarUnit|NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit|NSWeekdayCalendarUnit
                        fromDate:[NSDate date]];
[components setYearForWeekOfYear:2012];
[components setWeekOfYear:52];
[components setWeekday:2];
```

With this modification, the output is

```
date time is 17 Dec 2012 To 23 Dec 2012
```

on both iOS 5 and iOS 6.

Comment: i used your method but it does'nt gives me expected result.i am not getting same value for IOS 5 and IOS6. pls help.

Comment: @saurabh: Hm, it worked for me (tested in iOS 5 and 6 Simulator), so it is difficult to say why it does not work for you. What results do you get now? What is the expected result? Can you add the new code to your question?

Comment: i just replaced  your components part with my code but got the answer 17 Dec 2012 To 23 Dec 2012 for ios 6 and
24 dec. 2012 To 30 dec. 2012 for ios 5 
what i need is i use to call a loop to get past 6 weeks. when i go to week no 1 of 2013 it will give date range for 52 week of 2012  which i get different for ios6 and ios 5.